# How to select email id if the username matches in python

Tags: python

```
user_list = ['ravi.teja', 'teja.ravi', 'arun.kumar']

email_ids = ['ravi.teja@gmail.com', 'teja.ravi@gmail.com', 'arun.kumar@gmail.com']
```

I am trying to match the email with the username `firstname.lastnam`e from `user_list` and if the `firstname.lastname` in the `user_list` matches the `firstname.lastname@gmail.com` in the `email_ids` i need to send an email to the respective person.

Example

```
for i in user_list:
    username = i
    for e in email_ids:
        em = e.split("@")[0]
        if username == em:
           send_email(i,em)  """ I need to select the email based on the condition to send email only to the match i.e ravi.teja == ravi.teja send email to ravi.teja@gmail.com or teja.ravi == teja.ravi send email to teja.ravi@gmail.com

can some one help me how to select an email_address if the firstname and the last name in the email id matches the exact string."""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for username in user_list:
    for e in email_ids:
        em = e.split("@")[0]
        if username == em:
            send_email(e)
```

I am assuming your `send_email()` function takes in a string argument of email address here